# IOS function Call free use Sinch framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, sinch

I'm working about call free function, and I'm using Sinch frameworks.
Link tutorial:

https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios-simple-voice-app-tutorial/#adding a callscreenviewcontroller

And I had met this error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: can't resolve symbol __Z24REBSTDStringFromNSStringP8NSString in /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/60DDDF05-3DFF-464C-83EB-AE4BB0B8533E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/575C9C20-13DF-4926-96E5-DD79D9367B0A/myapp.app/myapp because dependent dylib #9 could not be loaded
dyld: can't resolve symbol __Z24REBSTDStringFromNSStringP8NSString in /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/60DDDF05-3DFF-464C-83EB-AE4BB0B8533E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/575C9C20-13DF-4926-96E5-DD79D9367B0A/myapp.app/myapp because dependent dylib #9 could not be loaded.
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: I think that this question was not really relevant to sinch, it was a cocoapod, linking frameworks in general problem. Can you please confirm below answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a mix of using cocoapods and static linking of the same framework, together with some config on the other linker flags.